# Does changing variable in one function doesnot effect the variable in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, scope

```
def happy(num):
    while len(str(num))>1:
        finding=hfind(num)
    if finding==1:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("false")
    
def hfind(num):
    total=0
    for i in str(num):
        total+=int(i)*2
    num=total
    return(num)
    
happy(100)
```

I wrote code for [Happy Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number) but,i don't know why it is not printing any output.

Can anybody explain clearly especially using this problem.

Comment: It doesn't make any change because they are two different variables in disjoint scopes.  Please do the expected work to trace your code's operation and values, and ask a *specific* question about what you don't understand.
See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to reassign the value of `num` inside the loop.
2. Use `** 2` to square a number.
3. You need to check if the number reached `4` to prevent an infinite loop.

```
def happy(num):
    while num != 1 and num != 4:
        num = hfind(num)
    if num == 1:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("false")
    
def hfind(num):
    total=0
    for i in str(num):
        total += int(i) ** 2
    return total
    
happy(100)
```

Comment: why you used num!=1 and num!=4

Comment: @NAIDU To prevent an infinite loop if it is not a happy number.